# maven missing multiple artifacts when using ejb-jee6-was archetype from com.ibm.tools.archetype group

Tags: maven, maven-2, websphere, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to create new project using **ejb-jee6-was** archetype but after project has been created get the following error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.jpa:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wsfp:com.ibm.wsfp.main:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.prereq.xlxp:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.web2mobile:RPCAdapter-annotation:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:wsadie.marshall:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.tivoli.tam:PD:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:dhbcore:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.prereq.wsdl4j:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.rsadbutils:rsadbutils:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.admin.services:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:com.ibm.mq.connector:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.mail-impl:mail-impl:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.web2mobile:webmsg_applib:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.emf:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.sdo:jar:
     1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.runtime:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.runtime.dist:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.osgi.4.2:osgi.cmpn:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.web2mobile:wink-jaxrs-webdav:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:com.ibm.mq:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact 
     com.ibm.websphere.org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:com.ibm.mq.jmqi:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.jsf.myfaces:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.jaxrs:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:com.ibm.mq.pcf:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.prereq.jackson:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.web2mobile:RPCAdapter:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.sip.container:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:wsadie.wsatlib:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.j2ee:j2ee:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.wccm:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.osgi.4.2:osgi.core:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.sca.2.0:sca_api:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.sip.interface:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.prereq.vajava:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact 
     com.ibm.websphere.org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.commonj.sdo:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.bootstrap:bootstrap:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:com.ibm.mq.commonservices:jar:
     1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi:jar:
     1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.org.apache:org.apache.tuscany.sca.api:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ffdcSupport:ffdcSupport:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.batch.runtime:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.sca.1.0:sca_api:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.admin.core:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.wmq.jmsra:com.ibm.mq.headers:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.xml:xmlapi:jar:1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.org.eclipse.emf:org.eclipse.emf.common:jar:
     1.0.0
    - Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.ws:com.ibm.ws.sib.server:jar:1.0.0
```

Adding the following dependency didn't help:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Liberty</id>
            <name>Liberty Repository</name>
            <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

The most strange thing that when I try to create project from following archetype: **webapp-jee7-liberty** everything works fine.

What can I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependent artifacts for was-liberty are published on Liberty Repository you mentioned above.  The archetype for "ejb-jee6-was" uses a target pom emulating was-classic 8.5.5, and requires an initial install step to populate your local Maven repository.

Follow the instructions for setting up WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHR6W_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm

Comment: So, if I need to developing ejb-jee6-was for Websphere 8, I need to install it first. Then install local maven repository, and then create a project, right?